# Pass a value to a portlet in popup - Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am opening a popup in liferay with a portlet in it. I want to pass a value in it so that the variable will be available in the doView() method.

```
    $('#<portlet:namespace/>myInfo').on('click', function(event) {
        url = '<%=myUrl%>';
        Liferay.Util.openWindow({
            title : "My Info",
            uri : url,
            id : 'myWindow',
            dialog : {
                destroyOnClose : true,
                cache : false,
                modal : true,
                width : 1070,
                height : 800
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is myUrl value here? You can pass parameter in url itself :)

Comment: @PankajKathiriya <liferay-portlet:renderURL var="myURL"
 portletName="addGames_WAR_GameToolportlet"
 windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>" />

Comment: `<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="myURL" portletName="addGames_WAR_GameToolportlet"  windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>" ><liferay-portlet:param name="paramName" value="paramValue"/></liferay-portlet:renderURL>` . You can have something like this.